# Where is an application stored installed with AUR support ?(manjaro linux)

Tags: linux, manjaro

I recently installed Armorpaint from "Add/Remove software" in manjaro linux with AUR support. And I'm not finding where is its executable file stored.Can you please help?

Comment: `pacman -Ql package_name`

Comment: It still doesn't show the executable file

Comment: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=armorpaint-git#n49 Also read the shell script itself to find out what exactly it runs.

Comment: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/armorpaint.sh?h=armorpaint-git

Comment: @TomYan, Thanks!